# Can I index a tree in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, tree, nosql

I need to create a tree with tens of levels and thousands of nodes, and then find a given document by field inside that tree.

Is it possible to index that field in the whole tree?

And what would the query to find that document look like?

Answer (score 2):

You want to store a graph, use a graph database.